# XML::Simple and Annoying Output

Tags: xml, perl

I'm trying to parse a XML file, and I get all the time an output like

```
HASH(0x2aed088)
```

here is my code

```
$xml = new XML::Simple;
$data = $xml->XMLin('test',keyattr => { 'name' => 'count' });
$check = sprintf($data);
print $check."\n";
```

Can you help me ?

Bests

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you convert a reference to a hash to a string? You need to pull the data you actually care about out of it.

Comment: If you can give a sample of XML and expected output, I'll draft an `XML::Twig` solution.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<M3Monitors version="1.0">
  <parameters/>
  <category name="name" description="Autojobs jobs currently running in the system" count="61" timestamp="2015-01-16T14:24:31"> trying to extract the count value

Comment: Probably easier to put that into your question.

Comment: Are you sure that's your XML? Because it's malformed - you don't close the 'M3Monitors' tag, for example.

Comment: hi, the xml is not malformed I didin't post the whole file and I forget to close the tag. Thanks for your answer it 's working for the example but when I put the whole file it's not working.

Comment: Give me a fuller example, and I'll give you a more accurate answer :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because when you parse your XML, it turns it into a perl data structure - typically a hash, and because XML is hierarchical, that'll probably mean a hash of hashes.

To print it out, you need to 'unpack' the hash. Usually that's called 'pretty_printing'. In `XML::Simple`, that's `XMLout`.

Or you can iterate on the hash keys, but bear in mind you may need to recurse several layers if you do that.

Alternatively, you can use `Data::Dumper`:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper (\$data);
```

Personally, I'd suggest also looking at one of the XML libraries - `XML::Simple` isn't. (I like [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm))

Based on comments above:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <M3Monitors version="1.0"> <parameters/> <category name="name" description="Autojobs jobs currently running in the system" count="61" timestamp="2015-01-16T14:24:31"/></M3Monitors>';

my $parser = XML::Twig->new();
$parser->parse($xml);

my $count = $parser->root->first_child('category')->att('count');
print $count;
```

Although note - I've had to amend your XML, because the bit that's in the comment is malformed. If you're getting malformed XML as your source data, then XML parsing is going to be very painful - the design spec of XML says 'broken XML is fatal' http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

I have edited it - this is bad form, but I have done so purely to illustrate how `XML::Twig` 'does it'. You should never try to 'fix' broken XML normally. It's a data structure, and if it's not valid, it's not valid. It's simply not safe to make assumptions about what it *should* be.

Comment: There's a summary of XML libraries on [mstpan](http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-3/).

Comment: That's a good summary. I think `XML::Simple` is assumed to be telling the truth. SMTP and SNMP have much the same problem ;)

Comment: The problem with `XML::Simple` is that the name makes people think it is a simple way to deal with XML instead of what it is, which is a way to deal with simple XML.

Comment: the output of the dumper is the whole file, I 'm gonna check with XML::Twig

Comment: What are you actually trying to extract from your XML? And can you give an example of your source? `XML::Twig` has the same problem - it's not psychic, you need to tell it what to extract.